# \flushbottom vs. fixing position of chapter heading in book class

Tags: sectioning

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt%,oneside%
]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%\raggedbottom
\chapter{ABC}
See how this chapter heading is not in the same place as the following one? Try the oneside option of the book class, and the problem disappears!
\chapter{ABC}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

You'll note the positions of the first and second chapter headings are different. This is quite annoying when switching from one doublepage to another after a very short chapter.

How can I fix this without using `\raggedbottom` or `oneside`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug, er, feature in the `book` class, where `\par` is used for separating “Chapter 1” from the title, but `\parskip` is not set to zero. The usual setting for `\parskip` is `0pt plus 1pt`, in order for TeX to be able to obey `\flushbottom`.

Just correct the bad behavior:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  openany,% just to be able to see both chapter heads side by side
]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\parindent}
  {\parskip=\z@skip\parindent}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}

See how this chapter heading is not in the same place as the following one? Try the oneside
option of the book class, and the problem disappears!

\chapter{ABC}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

The setting `\parskip=\z@skip` is local, because LaTeX does the printing of the chapter head in a group, so it won't propagate to the text typesetting.

Comment: Thanks! I use `titlesec` with `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]`, and so I had to replace `\@makechapterhead` by `\ttlh@hang` (I guess that stands for _title header hanging_). Working great so far!

Comment: Since you use `titlesec` did you think of setting the option `rigidchapters` rather than the default `rubberchapters`?

Comment: Actually, I didn't know about it :) It looks more difficult to apply in my case, though, because my chapter headings have a variable number of lines and the text starts on the same page. With just `rigidchapters` and no corrections, multiline headings overlap with the text, or text is far away from single-line headings. I am very happy with patching `\ttlh@hang`.