# Komascript fix vertical position of chapter heading with \flushbottom

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, scrbook

I adjusted the format of chapter headings like in the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618726/koma-chapter-titles-same-height-for-numbered-and-unnumbered-chapters) (`scrbook` class). I'm using the `\flushbottom` option. When for instance the list of figures spans more than one page, the vertical position of the chapter heading is changed a little bit. I tried to fix the rubber length of `\parskip` based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194899/flushbottom-vs-fixing-position-of-chapter-heading-in-book-class). This did not work as intended (see image). Is there a way to fix the vertical position without using `\raggedbottom`? Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    parskip=half,
    openany,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[showframe,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnLeft]{hyperref}

\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=true}
\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand{\chapapp}{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    prefixfont = \bfseries\fontsize{50}{52}\selectfont,
    font = \Huge,
    beforeskip = 40pt,
    innerskip = -5pt,
    afterskip = 40pt,
]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}
        {{\usekomafont{#1prefix}{%
                    \mbox{}%
                    \setlength{\@tempskipa}{\csname scr@#1@innerskip\endcsname}\chapterheadmidvskip
            }}#3%
        }% Unnumbered chapter headings
        {#2#3}% Numbered chapter headings
    }
    {#2#3}% Other headings using style=chapter
}
\makeatother

% Fix position of chapter heading (not working)
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
{\parindent}
{\parskip=\z@skip\parindent}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\blindtext[4]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```